# I'm new to proofs, does anybody have a proof that three times a prime is always greater than the next consecutive prime?

Tags: proof-explanation

Numbering the primes in the fashion {|P<sub>1</sub> -> 2 | P<sub>2</sub> -> 5 | P<sub>3</sub> -> 7 | P<sub>4</sub> -> 11 | ... |},

Can I prove that 3P<sub>n</sub> > P<sub>n+1</sub>? My gut is kind of telling me it's true, but I'm not really sure how to go about proving (or disproving) it without knowing something to do with the maximum gaps between primes, or something like that?

Comment: Look up Bertrand's postulate, which is stronger than you need.

Comment: @PatrickStevens It could be interesting to see whether this problem is significantly easier to prove, though.